# In Android memory,Graphs mean what and why it's so large?

Tags: android, android-memory

I found my app always use many memory,maybe 150~300MB,but these apps are simple,no many imgs,no videos,just some fragments with a activity,also 10+ icons,when I view Android Profiler,I found  memory graph is very large,over 50%, 80MB+,I think not memory leaks cause it,because in first activity or fragment,not do other action,Graph will be larger than 80MB.why it so large?

I create a empty project only one hello activity,Profiler show below:

[image]

Graphics is 24MB,code is below:

```
package cn.candrwow.simple;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

can you teach me how to reduce it?Thank you!

Comment: Have you read https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler?

Comment: Hi,I read it before,but I am confused about the concept of OOM and dalvik.vm.heapsize,I don't sure heapsize equals which one,java,native or total,in android setting->app->memory,max usage equals Profiler's total,so in development, which one should I focus on?Who caused memory leaks and oom?